# Multiple .obj Models in THREE.js and detecting clicked objects

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I have been following along [this](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html) example to load .obj Model using three.js. Since I needed more than one model to load so I tried this

```
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

var object = event.content;

object.position.y = - 80;
scene.add( object );

});
loader.load( 'obj/model1.obj' );
loader.load( 'obj/model2.obj' );
```

First: I don't know whether this is the right approach or not since I searched but didn't find any tutorial loading more than one .obj models.

Second: I want to be able to click different models on the screen. I tried [this](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html) which doest not seem to work for me. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example shows you a pattern for loading multiple models:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_json_objconverter.html

Regarding detecting clicked objects, depending on your model, you may need to set the `recursive` flag to `true`:

```
ray.intersectObjects( objects, true );
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you haven't provide enough code to fully explain you question I will guess that for the second part you have to make sure you put the objects in an array of objects such as:

```
var objects = [];
```

after initializing the objects you do:

```
objects.push( object );
```

now you have an array where you can check for objects intersected after implementing the THREE.Ray.